# Change one-dimensional tuple using slicing / object reassignment

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

I understand that tuples are immutable objects, however, I know tuples support indexing and slicing.  Thus, if I have a tuple assigned to a variable, I can reassign the variable to a new tuple object and change the value at the desired index position.

When I attempt to do this using an index slice, I am getting returned a tuple containing multiple tuples.  I understand why this is happening, because I am passing comma separated slices of the original tuple, but I can't figure out how (if possible) I can return a one-dimensional tuple with a single element changed when working with larger sets of data.

Example:

```
someNumbers = tuple(i for i in range(0, 20))
print(someNumbers)
someNumbers = someNumbers[:10], 2000, someNumbers[11:]
print(someNumbers)
```

Outputs the following:

```
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)
((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), 2000, (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19))
```

Can I return a one-dimensional tuple and change only the desired index value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [concatenation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations):

```
someNumbers = someNumbers[:10] + (2000,) + someNumbers[11:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuple concatenation:

```
someNumbers = tuple(i for i in range(0, 20))
print(someNumbers)
# (2000, ) to differentiate it from (2000) which is a number
someNumbers = someNumbers[:10]+ (2000,) + someNumbers[11:]
print(someNumbers)
```

Outputs:

```
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2000, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)
```